# unknown option -keyformat : How to fix?

Tags: terminal, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to migrate to the new APNs Provider API via [Sending Push Notifications Using Command-Line](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools) . After setting the following shell variables per the Apple Documentation:

```
CERTIFICATE_FILE_NAME=path to the certificate file

CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE_NAME=path to the private key file

TOPIC=App ID

DEVICE_TOKEN=device token for your app

APNS_HOST_NAME=api.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

And hoping that I amended the terminal command correctly to test that I can connect to APNs using my SSL certificate:

```
% openssl s_client -connect "${APNS_HOST_NAME}":443 -cert "${CERTIFICATE_FILE_NAME}" -certform DER -key "${CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE_NAME}" -keyformat PEM
```

**What I entered in the terminal:**

```
openssl s_client -connect api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443 -cert aps.cer -certform DER -key PushChatKey.p12 -keyformat PEM
```

The terminal output is:

```
unknown option -keyformat
usage: s_client args

 -4            - Force IPv4
 -6            - Force IPv6
 -host host     - use -connect instead
 -port port     - use -connect instead
 -connect host:port - who to connect to (default is localhost:4433)
 -proxy host:port - connect to http proxy
 -verify arg   - turn on peer certificate verification
 -cert arg     - certificate file to use, PEM format assumed
 -certform arg - certificate format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -key arg      - Private key file to use, in cert file if
             not specified but cert file is.
 -keyform arg  - key format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -pass arg     - private key file pass phrase source
 -CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
 -CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
 -reconnect    - Drop and re-make the connection with the same Session-ID
 -pause        - sleep(1) after each read(2) and write(2) system call
 -showcerts    - show all certificates in the chain
 -debug        - extra output
 -msg          - Show protocol messages
 -nbio_test    - more ssl protocol testing
 -state        - print the 'ssl' states
 -nbio         - Run with non-blocking IO
 -crlf         - convert LF from terminal into CRLF
 -quiet        - no s_client output
 -ign_eof      - ignore input eof (default when -quiet)
 -no_ign_eof   - don't ignore input eof
 -tls1_2       - just use TLSv1.2
 -tls1_1       - just use TLSv1.1
 -tls1         - just use TLSv1
 -dtls1        - just use DTLSv1
 -mtu          - set the link layer MTU
 -no_tls1_2/-no_tls1_1/-no_tls1/-no_ssl3/-no_ssl2 - turn off that protocol
 -bugs         - Switch on all SSL implementation bug workarounds
 -cipher       - preferred cipher to use, use the 'openssl ciphers'
             command to see what is available
 -starttls prot - use the STARTTLS command before starting TLS
             for those protocols that support it, where
             'prot' defines which one to assume.  Currently,
             only "smtp", "lmtp", "pop3", "imap", "ftp" and "xmpp"
             are supported.
 -xmpphost host - connect to this virtual host on the xmpp server
 -sess_out arg - file to write SSL session to
 -sess_in arg  - file to read SSL session from
 -servername host  - Set TLS extension servername in ClientHello
 -tlsextdebug      - hex dump of all TLS extensions received
 -status           - request certificate status from server
 -no_ticket        - disable use of RFC4507bis session tickets
 -alpn arg         - enable ALPN extension, considering named protocols supported (comma-separated list)
 -groups arg       - specify EC curve groups (colon-separated list)
 -use_srtp profiles - Offer SRTP key management with a colon-separated profile list
 -keymatexport label   - Export keying material using label
 -keymatexportlen len  - Export len bytes of keying material (default 20)
```

Terminal Update After Trying `-keyform`

`Error opening client certificate private key file PushChatKey.p12 4442713772:error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/e90674e518/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:255:fopen('PushChatKey.p12', 'r') 4442713772:error:20FFF002:BIO routines:CRYPTO_internal:system lib:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/e90674e518/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:257: unable to load client certificate private key file`

Comment: Possibly `-keyform` as listed in the usage output?

Comment: @msbit examples?

Comment: Just replace `-keyformat` with `-keyform`?

Comment: I tried `-keyform` and this is the output?

Comment: I updated the question with the terminal output after trying `-keyform` instead of `-keyformat`

Comment: `No such file or directory`, I'm guessing `PushChatKey.p12` either doesn't exist or isn't in the current working directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236252/discussion-between-programcode-and-msbit).